# Conditional Summing with multiple columns in R

Tags: r, time, data.table

I want to plot points per user versus time but I am not sure what to do to the columns in order to achieve that result. This is what my data looks like:

```
> head(data, n=3)
points   user       time
25        1      02/22/2017
0         2      02/26/2017
15        3      02/27/2017

> dput(data)
structure(list(points = c(25, 0, 15), user = c(1, 2, 3), time = c("02/22/2017", "02/26/2017", "02/27/2017")), .Names = c("points", "user", "time"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

FYI there are multiple users ids (I think up to 15). However what I want to do is sum the total points per user (then number in the user column corresponds to the user's id number. And then plot those values over time (by day specifically).

This is the code I use to generate the total points per user

```
library(data.table)
ppu = setkey(setDT(df), user_id)[, list(points=sum(points)), by=list(user_id)]
```

Which gives the following result:

[image]

But I want to find the total points per user per day! I would really appreciate any guidance.

Comment: If you intend for anybody to actually use your data, please post *actual data*, not *pictures of data*. (It should take less effort to copy/paste R console text than screen-shot, save, upload, post.)

Comment: @r2evans When I copy the R console text it gets all messy - is there an easy way of doing this? I'm using R and not R studio.

Comment: Have you tried using `dput` for the data?

Comment: The trick is to prepend 4 spaces on each line. Try highlighting the console text, then run this (assuming win, similar techniques work for mac/linux): `writeLines(gsub("^", "    ", readLines("clipboard")), "clipboard")` (the second string should be four-spaces) and then paste into your question. This forces StackOverflow to code-format the output ("verbatim").

Comment: There's also [`reprex`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reprex/index.html) that does something similar.

Comment: Ok awesome, I will do that and then edit the question so you can use the actual data.

Comment: I'll second @student's comment, though: it's much easier for us to *consume* if you use `dput(data)` (or `dput(head(data))` if large), since we can literally copy/paste and get the data. Otherwise, we need a little `read.table` magic, not always "easy enough".

Comment: Another side-comment: I recommend *against* naming a variable `data`. If you ever run the script without creating the variable, instead of a useful error message (`Error: object 'x' not found`), you'll get something a bit more obscure (`Error in data$x : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`, which really means that I tried to subset the [*function* named `data()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/data.html)).

Comment: Oh ok - thank you for the heads up. I will definitely not name my variables data now.

Comment: So I would just run dput(head(data)) in R and then I copy and paste the result into stack exchange and that would be enough for you to get the data?

Comment: Sure, see my suggested edit to your question. I did a little manual editing (removed inline newlines), but the same technique for copy/pasting the dataframe output works with output from `dput`.

Comment: @r2evans Highlight the text in the SO text entry box, and type Ctrl-K.

Comment: You're kidding me (*now* [I find it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)) ... oh well, my hacks still work, even if they are more keystrokes ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, try (with `df` as given by the result of the `dput()` in the Q):

```
library(data.table)   # version 1.10.4 used
ppu <- setDT(df)[, .(points = sum(points)), by = .(user, time)]

ppu
#   user       time points
#1:    1 02/22/2017     25
#2:    2 02/26/2017      0
#3:    3 02/27/2017     15
```

This will return `user`, `time` in the order they appear in `df`. If you want to have the result sorted, you have two choices:

E.g., for printing, use

```
ppu[order(user, time)]
# or
ppu[order(time, user)]
```

or, if the result should be keyed, try `keyby`:

```
ppu <- setDT(df)[, .(points = sum(points)), keyby = .(user, time)]
```

Some remarks:

- Your code snippet uses `user_id` while your data sample uses `user`. Also, the data sample includes a column named `time` which contains dates as character strings but in the text you are using the term "day".
- `by` accepts more than one grouping variable. You even can create expressions *on the fly*.
- As simplification, `time` doesn't need to be coerced to class `Data` as long as same dates are being written the same way.
- In `data.table` syntax, .`()` is an abbreviation for `list()`.
- The recent versions of `data.table` have lifted the requirement to set keys.

---

In [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43284579/conditional-summing-with-multiple-columns-in-r#comment73683389_43292626), the OP asked how

> to plot the amount of points per user vs time (per day).

This requires some modfications to `ppu` to work better with `ggplot2`.

```
# coerce user to factor to get a discrete colour scale
# only required here because user was given as numeric 
ppu[, user := factor(user)]
# coerce time from character to Date class
# to get a nicely scaled x-axis instead of discrete values
ppu[, time := lubridate::mdy(time)]
```

Now, `points` are plotted versus `time` but with a separate, colour-coded line for each `user`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(ppu, aes(time, points, group = user, colour = user)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line()
```

[image]

Well, you probably would see lines here if there were enough sample data ...

Comment: Thank you so much - this worked very well. So instead of setting keys what would I do? Also if I wanted to plot the amount of points per user vs time (per day), how would I go about doing that? I would think that I would plot ppu vs time but the length of ppu would be different than time.

Comment: @Chris95 I've updated my answer to include the plotting stuff. Hope I met your expectations. Concerning setting keys for small data.tables, you probably don't need to worry about setting keys at all thanks to the automatically created secondary indices.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert your dates to a nice format, for that I'd suggest you use `library(lubridate)` like this:

```
data$day <- mdy(data$day)
```

Then sum the number of points for each user for each day:

```
library(plyr)
pts_user_day <- ddply(data, .(user, day), summarise, pts_day = sum(points))
```

Finally plot all of this over time:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(pts_user_day, aes(x=day, y=pts_day, col=factor(user))) + geom_line() + scale_x_date()
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: The question is tagged `data.table`, the included code snippet contains `library(data.table)`. So, an answer using `plyr` might not be what the OP is expecting (even if your suggestion might lead to the same result).